# 'malloc' is unable to allocate memory for a float array for size 3 billion

Tags: c, malloc, out-of-memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been trying to allocate a 2-d contiguous array as:

```
float **objects;
long long len;
len = (*numObjs) * (*numCoords);
objects = (float **)malloc((*numObjs) * sizeof(float *));
assert(objects != NULL);
objects[0] = (float *)malloc(len * sizeof(float));
if (objects[0] == NULL) {
    perror("malloc" );
    abort();
}
for (i=1; i<(*numObjs); i++)
     objects[i] = objects[i-1] + (*numCoords);
```

where `(*numObjs) = 500 million` and `(*numCoords) = 6`.

The error shown by perror is:
`malloc: Cannot allocate memory`

For `(*numObjs) = 200 million`, its working fine. But for greater than that, its throwing the above error.

Also note that, I have around 14 GB free physical memory and huge free swap space available.

Comment: you are probably compiling as 32-bit instead of 64-bit. Check your compiler's options.

Comment: Your objects array is 4GB, and your object[0] array is 12GB. 12 + 4 = 16. I don't know if this would help but if you wanted to force it, you could try increasing the swapiness of your system (in linux dunno about windows).